# How to get token from facebook login [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an app that open a `webview` and let users sign in.

I'm trying to get the access token from the `baseUrl` but the access token disappeared after view moments in the link `access_token=` and show me another page have a not secure connection so I can't take it ...
here's my code

```
            DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            string r3 = page.Source.AbsoluteUri;
            string ntoken = r3.Substring(r3.IndexOf("access_token") + 13);
            string token = ntoken.Substring(0, ntoken.IndexOf("&"));
```

anyone can help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `LoadComplete` event and after that you can check every time if the link have the access token and if is there then hit your code by this way you can take the access token and close the `webview` before the other page start

```
    private void webview_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (page.Source.AbsoluteUri.Contains("access_token"))
        {
            DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            string r3 = page.Source.AbsoluteUri;
            string ntoken = r3.Substring(r3.IndexOf("access_token") + 13);
            string token = ntoken.Substring(0, ntoken.IndexOf("&"));
            web.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         }
     }
```